# Should ASP.Net MVC apps be more link-driven?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Strange question, I know, but one thing I seem to be feeling with ASP.Net MVC is that it's smoother and more logical to try and avoid form-submissions unless totally necessary (especially if you have more than 1 on a single view).

As an example, you have a list of items and you can sort the items, to me it seems to be a more 'fitting' implementation to have a handful of links that filter the list rather than say, a drop-down with a submit button next to it?

Is it just me or does anyone else feel that you need to run with a certain approach in order for ASP.Net MVC to achieve perhaps better maintainability?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With links users will benefit from seeing sorting in URL, being able to change it in URL, bookmark to specific sorting, and so on. They won't see "Data will be sent again" dialog box.

However, the post can create the correct url and redirect there, following the PRG (post/redirect/get) principle, allowing to use combo/submit without their drawbacks.

Comment: Do you find the PRG method could get a bit messy in ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Never had any problems with it.